# Nginx Proxy Manager - Memory Usage unclear

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Ngnix Proxy Manager with 100 proxy hosts running on an ubuntu with 32GB Ram. However, the RAM usage is constantly increasing.

i see differences between top, free -m and docker stats that i can't explain. nothing else is running on the machine except the two containers for nginx proxy manager.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some of the proxy hosts have chaching enabled, can this contribute to higher ram consumption?
Here are the configs for a proxy host:

[image]

[image]

in the logs i can't find anything conspicuous so far but i only see the access.logs now

can I start somewhere else here or am I missing something?

many thanks